# How can I use IIS administration commandlets on Windows Server 2012 R2?

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2012-r2, iis-8.5

I'm trying to use IIS administration commandlets such as Get-IISSite on a Windows Server 2012 R2 computer.

I've already installed IIS Server and all IIS Management Tools roles and rebooted the server.

[image: Installed Web Server Roles]

However, when I open a PS commandline as administrator, the commandlets are still missing:

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator> get-command *iis*

CommandType     Name                                               ModuleName
-----------     ----                                               ----------
Function        IIS:                                               WebAdministration
Application     iisreset.exe


PS C:\Users\Administrator>
```

What am I doing wrong?

**Edit**: One thing I've also already tried (without any luck):

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator> Import-Module webadministration
PS C:\Users\Administrator> get-command *iis*

CommandType     Name                                               ModuleName
-----------     ----                                               ----------
Function        IIS:                                               webadministration
Application     iisreset.exe


PS C:\Users\Administrator>
```

Comment: I don't see `Get-IISSite` listed [for 2012 R2](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/%5Clibrary/hh867899(v=wps.630).aspx), it doesn't appear until [Server Technical Preview/Windows 10](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt270167.aspx). What does `Import-Module WebAdministration; (Get-Module WebAdministration).ExportedCommands` have to say?

Comment: @jscott: that does indeed work (There's get-webserver instead of get-iis). Thanks for your help! However, now I'm confused. What is the difference between get-webserver and get-iis? it seems very similar.

Comment: Looking at the docs the main difference seems [`Get-WebSite`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh867835(v=wps.630).aspx) uses `-Name <String>` while [`Get-IISSite`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt270167.aspx) users `-Name <String[]>`. I haven't a Server Technical Preview available at the moment to provide a more useful response, sorry.

Comment: IIS Team Blog - Introducing IISAdministration in the PowerShell Gallery
https://blogs.iis.net/iisteam/introducing-iisadministration-in-the-powershell-gallery

Answer (score 2):

As jScott correctly remarked in the comments, Get-IISSite ist not included in Windows-Server 2012 R2, but only in later Windows Server versions and in Windows 10 or higher. `Import-Module WebAdministration; (Get-Module WebAdministration).ExportedCommands` is very similar and works under Windows Server 2012 R2 though.